# How do I use taylor's theorem to prove this approximation?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Show that $$(x^3 + x^2 + 1)^{1/3} - (x^2 + x)^{1/2} = -\frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{72x} + O\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right) $$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$.

I have tried to let $x^3 + x^2$ be one term, then expand it binomially. The other term I factorize out $x^{1/2}$ and expand it binomially as well. But no where can I find a $\frac{1}{x}$ term. Am I in the right direction?

Comment: You should expand binomally after pulling out $x^3$ from the first term and $x^2$ from second term. It'll work.

Answer (score 0):

$(x^3+x^2+1)^{1/3}−(x^2+x)^{1/2} = x(1+\dfrac{1}{x}+\dfrac{1}{x^2})^{1/3}+x(1+\dfrac{1}{x})^{1/2}$

$\Rightarrow x[1+\dfrac{1}{3}(\dfrac{1}{x}+\dfrac{1}{x^2})+\dfrac{-1}{9})(\dfrac{1}{x}+\dfrac{1}{x^2})^2+...]+x[1+\dfrac{1}{2x}+\dfrac{-1}{8x^2}+\dfrac{1}{16x^3}]$(using taylor thm.)

Now I guess you can simplify this to get the desired expression

Answer (score 0):

Set $x=1/t$ in the function we have

$$g(t)=\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{t^3}+\frac{1}{t^2}+1}-\sqrt{\frac{1}{t^2}+\frac{1}{t}}$$
$$\lim_{t\to 0} \, \left(\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{t^3}+\frac{1}{t^2}+1}-\sqrt{\frac{t+1}{t^2}}\right)=-\frac16\quad(*)$$
Furthermore
$$g'(t)=\frac{-\frac{3}{t^4}-\frac{2}{t^3}}{3 \left(\frac{1}{t^3}+\frac{1}{t^2}+1\right)^{2/3}}-\frac{-\frac{2}{t^3}-\frac{1}{t^2}}{2 \sqrt{\frac{1}{t^2}+\frac{1}{t}}}$$
$$\lim_{t\to 0}g'(t)=\frac{1}{72}$$
So expanding $g(t)$ with MacLaurin formula

$g(t)=g(0)+g'(0)t+O(t^2)$

we get

$g(t)=-\dfrac{1}{6}+\dfrac{1}{72}t+O(t^2)$

replacing $x=1/t$ we get

$f(x)=-\dfrac{1}{6}+\dfrac{1}{72x}+O\left(\dfrac{1}{x^2}\right)$

Hope this can be useful

$(*)$

Simplify
$$\lim_{t\to 0}\,\frac{\sqrt[3]{t^3+t+1}-\sqrt{t+1}}{t}$$
And apply L'Hopital rule
$$\lim_{t\to 0}\,\frac{3 t^2+1}{3 \left(t^3+t+1\right)^{2/3}}-\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{t+1}}=\frac13-\frac12=-\frac16$$

Comment: Thank you. how did you get $\frac{1}{6}$ in the second step?

Comment: @user102938475 I added a note in my answer...

Answer (score 0):

Put $x=1/t$ and then the expression simplifies to $$\frac{(1+t+t^{3})^{1/3}-(1+t)^{1/2}}{t}\tag{1}$$ Now the first term in numerator of $(1)$ can be written as $$1 + \frac{t}{3} - \frac{t^{2}}{9} + o(t^{2})$$ The second term in numerator of $(1) $ can also be written as $$1+\frac{t}{2}-\frac{t^{2}}{8}+o(t^{2})$$ and therefore the numerator of $(1)$ is $$-\frac{t} {6}+\frac{t^{2}}{72}+o(t^{2})$$ and hence the expression $(1)$ is $$-\frac{1}{6}+\frac{t}{72}+o(t)$$ Putting $t=1/x$ and noting that $o(t) =O(t^{2})$ we are done.

The series expansions above have been obtained via the use of general binomial theorem.